# How to setup Selenium 4 for old Chrome version?

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, selenium4

By some project reasons I have to use Selenium 4 (4.0.0-rc3) and Chrome version 71.
Of course the current chromedriver (version 94) doesn't work with old chrome.

I have downloaded the source code of chromium project for debugging and try to understand how actually driver works with selenium. Probably I will try to make my own driver version but at this moment it seems like an inefficient solution.

I am really stuck with this and will be happy to get any advice.
Is it possible just to configure driver by capabilities (or any parameters) for working with old chrome?

Comment: You want to work with `browser 94` `driver 71` and `selenium 4` configurations?

Comment: One part of solution uses `selenium 4`, the latest `chrome browser 94` and the latest `driver 94`. <br/>

For one more part of solution I have to use `selenium4` and `chrome browser 71`. In this case better to choose `driver 94` but I am ready to try to configure `driver 71`

Comment: @Siking  That should be posted as an answer rather than as a comment. Comments are temporary and cannot be accepted as an answer. There is no mechanism for converting comments to answers, so I cannot do it for you. You will need to copy your comment into the answer box and then delete your comment.

Answer (score 2):

The Chrome version you're targeting `Chrome 71` is already deprecated. Using Selenium 4 with this much obsolete version of Chrome will not work and I think apart from creating your own code piece, there is nothing much you can do.

Using such an obsolete piece of software, in this age of internet, will open a pot of bugs for you, and if you use this to connect to internet, then chances are people may exploit any hidden security vulnerabilities to attack your application.

I would strongly suggest you to talk within your project team to use an updated version of Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

[ChromeDriver 2.46](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads#h.p_ID_606) will work with Chrome 71.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I did not realize stuff like "did you look on page 2" is a decent answer. ;)